# Get attribute string after position

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a bunch of selectors with data attributes, like this

```
<span class="btn-input" data-input-goto="..."></span>
<span class="btn-input" data-input-suggest="..."></span>
<span class="btn-input" data-input-show="..."></span>
```

I want to get the string after 'data-input' so i can use it to execute some code.

Here's what i did,  with no success:

```
$(".btn-input").click(function(event) {

    var action = $('[attr^="data-input"]', this).substr(11);

});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a name of data attribute, you can try this, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffjcugLr/4/):

```
$(".btn-input").click(function(event) {
    var action = Object.keys($(this).data())[0] // inputSuggest
    .toLowerCase() // inputsuggest
    .replace('input', ''); // suggest
});
```

**Update:** And for work with multiple attributes I can suggest a code below [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffjcugLr/8)

```
$(".btn-input").click(function(event) {
    var actions = Object.keys($(this).data());

    var action = actions.filter(function(item) {
      return /^input/.test(item);
    })[0] || '';

    action = action.toLowerCase().replace('input', '');

});
```

Comment: this works ok, except that i notice that if there is more then 1 data attribute, it will get the first one in the list... i absolutely need to get the one that starts wit 'data-input-'